# Why can't I change the text in my child component

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

I writed a Single File Components to show something, here is the code

```
 <template>
    <el-link type="primary" @click="test()" >{{this.contentShow}}</el-link>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import moment from 'moment'
import {Watch, Prop,Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

export default class extends Vue{

    @Prop({ default: "111" }) private content!: string
    

    private contentShow = "11";
    
    private test(){
        alert("111");
    }

    @Watch('content')
    private contentChange(value: any) {
        this.contentShow = value;
        console.log(value);
    }
}
</script>
```

I wanted to change the content of the el-link, but I failed. Here is the code

```
<userButton content="tttteeeessssttt"></userButton>
```

From the website console I can see that the method "contentChange" was not be used.

By the way, I tried to write like this:

```
<el-link type="primary" @click="test()" >{{this.content}}</el-link>
```

But there is wrong which says

> vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "content" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

So what's the wrong? How could I change the content of my component?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try removing private modifier of the content property.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you misunderstood about child component and props?

You need three `.vue` files to fulfill your requirements.

One is below.

```html
<template>
  <el-link type="primary" @click="test()" >{{this.contentShow}}</el-link>
</template>
```

Let's call it parent.vue.

The second one is the one you haven't disclosed.

```html
<template>
  <userButton content="tttteeeessssttt"></userButton>
</template>
```

Let's call it el-link.vue.
Or are you using Element-UI?

The third is userButton.vue.
It probably exists.

It is in userButton.vue that you need to write `content` in `props`.
It is meaningless to write in parent.vue.

It seems to me that you want to have the original `content` in parent.vue.
If so, you should define a variable named `content` in parent.vue.
It is not in `props`.

`content` must be written in the el-link.vue `props`.

Use `v-bind` to propagate `content` from parent.vue to el-link.vue.
Add `:content="content"` to `<el-link>`.

Similarly, propagate `content` from el-link.vue to userButton.vue.
Add `:content="content"` to `<userButton>`.